# Mobile Wireless Technology

Tags: wireless, mobile

Nowadays, most smartphones (or other smart mobiles) have some kind of wireless communication for short range and medium range. For short range, the most widespread technology in use is, probably, WiFi:

- standard: IEEE 802.11
- indoor range: 15m
- outdoor range: 40m
- frequency: 2.4GHz
- power consumption: 100mW
- throughput: 5Mbps

For medium range, the most widespread technology in use is, probably, GSM:

- standard: ETSI GSM
- urban range: 500m
- frequency: 1500MHz
- power consumption: 1W
- throughput: 300kbps

The differences between such technologies are mainly due to the communication protocols and the operating frequencies. Each one optimized for its own specifications.

**1st Issue**
Sometimes, when a technology has several updates and add-ons (as is in this case), it is not that easy to develop a simple comparison table. Therefore, does the simplified comparison above make sense or is it too unrealistic?

**2nd Issue**
It is well know that software developers can use WiFi features to transfer packets directly between mobiles. However, if you want to increase the range, is there any hardware constraint that would undermine using the GSM radio module (or other widespread mobile wireless technology for medium range) to transfer packets directly between smart mobiles?

Comment: Actually with the cellular networks like GSM (and not only it) you can communicate with any point in the world where there is network coverage, because networks are interconnected. That is why I don't think it is middle range communication, but quite long range communication. As far as I know there is no way to use the mobile to directly connect to another one without using the network infrastructure.  and if there is it may be illegal, because the spectrum is not free for use..

Comment: @vladiz _I don't think it is middle range communication, but quite long range_ The range I've mentioned is within the data-link level. Of course, if we consider a multi-hop scenario the range would be infinite, but this is not the case.

Comment: @vladiz _there is no way to use the mobile to directly connect to another one_ Ok, bad news. However, just as food for though: there are some apps claiming to be walk-talkies and ram radios for smartphones (I don't know the specifics).

Comment: If you are talking about Push-to-talk over cellular, it uses the network. The connection is not directly between the two UEs. And it have to be supported by the mobile operator. The apps you are talking about may use Wifi. Can you tell which exactly apps are these? I am interested, too.

Comment: _If you are talking about Push-to-talk over cellular, it uses the network._ I'm not talking about PTT carriers (pe: Nextel).

Comment: _Can you tell which exactly apps are these?_ I have seen several videos showing walkie-talkie and ham radios apps for smartphones. However, I've never tested such apps and never dig very deeper the specifics of them. So, with that in mind, take a look at this video: [Very cheap Zello crosslink to PMR446 radio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lS8aAG7fBaY). It seems that the app is using a radio module of the smartphone other than the WiFi or Bluetooth.

Comment: @vladiz If this app is really using a radio module other than the WiFi or Bluetooth, which one is it? Can it be used for direct communication between mobiles? What would be the range? It would be very nice if it could be possible to transfer packets between smartphones for distances longer than the 20m of WiFi.

Comment: This is just an ordinary app for voice chat it uses connection to the  Internet over WiFi or the cellular network. It is like a  
Walkie Talkie (Puch-to-talk) in the Internet and the man which makes the video routed the audio output and the mic from the PC to the PMR

Comment: _just an ordinary app for voice chat it uses connection to the Internet_ Ok, bad news. I guess the same is true for the following video: [Zello BriLINC - iPhone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LC7RVSgtHDs). Although it seems to be a direct communication between the smartphone and the walkie-talkie, it is not. Right?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @RonMaupin _> "Did any answer help you?"_ Several comments helped to understand the issue, however, the only answer provided is too limited. I'm not going to accept it.

Comment: OK. You are free to leave the question open if you think you may get an acceptable answer, or you can close the question if you don't believe you will get an answer or it is no longer relevant.

Comment: @RonMaupin _> "if you think you may get an acceptable answer"_ Considering the question was made a long time ago, I don't think people would be interested in answer it. However, I still consider it relevant.

Comment: @RonMaupin _> "you can close the question"_ How to close it? Or you mean delete it?

Comment: OK. Yes, you could delete it if you do not think it will ever get an answer. You can leave it, but I don't see the point if it is not going to get you an acceptable answer. It's your decision.

Comment: @RonMaupin > _"[...] it is not going to get you an acceptable answer."_ Considering that I'm anxious to accept an answer, I wouldn't say that. I prefer saying that the chances of someone get excited enough to answer this issue is very low (however, not impossible).

Comment: If you are anxious to get an answer, you can offer a reward of reputation points. That will get attention.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can use GSM in a peer to peer manner; but even if you would devise a way to do it in software (that is, rewrite the firmware in a GSM radio or such), I'd guess the range would not be as if you're communicating via a BTS, as both sides would be using poor, built-in antenna.

Comment: _I'd guess the range would not be as if you're communicating via a BTS_ Ok, good point. I agree with you. I'm wondering how much the range would decrease due to that ...

Comment: _even if you would devise a way to do it in software_ This is another important issue, whether the operating system would allow you to use the GSM radio. However, I guess this is off-topic here at 'Network Engineering'. Later I will ask this software issue on another 'StackExchange' forum.

Comment: First of all, there is a project called OsmocomBB, which implements a lot of the GSM stack, and can be loaded in some phones, and used with some basestations. I've never used, as I've never found out how to do so, since the documentation is kind of chaotic. But it's there.

Comment: As for the range, it's hard to guess. I just tried some numbers with this calculator, and 2dBi antenna has approximately 1/3 the range of 9dBi antenna. Although I have no idea which antennae are used in GSM networks, I would guess the phone antenna would be approximately 2dBi, and the BTS would have much better one (as I have 9dBi at home). But that's not the only parameter, as it heavily depends on the receiver sensitivity as well. In the end, I think you'd end up somewhere in the WiFi ballpark, but with a lot of trouble on your hands.

Comment: _2dBi antenna has approximately 1/3 the range of 9dBi antenna_ This is interesting. It means that, at most, the connection between two phones would have 1/3 of the range of the connection between a phone and a BTS. So, if we consider the range of a phone/BTS to be 500m, then the range of a phone/phone would be at most 150m. Which is still 10 times better than the WiFi range. Very interesting ...

Comment: Also, as far as I know, the frequency used for GSM is less attenuated by walls (and similar stuff) than the frequency used by WiFi.

Comment: _there is a project called OsmocomBB_ Very interesting. At first glance it seems that their main focus is related to those old 'black boxes' phone mobiles before the smartphone era. I'm wondering if the smartphones are still that 'closed'.

Comment: BTS antennas have very wide variety. Antenna gain can be within the range 2dbi - 20dbi. BTS transmit power can be about 40W and the coverage range can be about 30km. And don't forget that the BTS antennas are usually situated on top of buildings, on towers. And in case of direct communication between two radios there would be much more obstacles decreasing the signal

Comment: _BTS antennas have very wide variety._ Ok, but can all this variety be used to estimate what would be the range between two smar mobiles?

Comment: _BTS antennas are usually situated on top of buildings_ Ok, I agree with you. The attenuation in most cases would be higher. Any idea how much?